# How to improve an algorithm where we merge lines of an array

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I ‘ve got an array like this =>
this is a result from a google analytics request. I asked for the amout of visits for the last three months.

```
$statPerMonth
array (size=2)
  '08' =>     // The month (August)
    array (size=34)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string '08' (length=2) // Month again
          1 => string 'admin.testweb.fr' (length=19) // host
          2 => string '1' (length=1)  // amount of visits
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string '08' (length=2)
          1 => string 'audigie-espace-auto.reseau-fivestar.fr' (length=38)
          2 => string '6' (length=1)
      2 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string '08' (length=2)
          1 => string 'www.audigie-espace-auto.reseau-fivestar.fr' (length=31)
          2 => string '9' (length=1)
      3 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string '08' (length=2)
          1 => string 'carrosserie-abberis.reseau-fivestar.fr' (length=38)
          2 => string '7' (length=1)
'07' => 
    array (size=47)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string '07' (length=2)
          1 => string 'www.anothersite.testweb.fr' (length=13)
          2 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string '07' (length=2)
          1 => string 'admin.testweb.fr' (length=16)
          2 => string '2' (length=1)
      2 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string '07' (length=2)
          1 => string 'admin.testweb.fr' (length=19)
          2 => string '1' (length=1)
      3 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string '07' (length=2)
          1 => string 'audigie-espace-auto.reseau-fivestar.fr' (length=38)
          2 => string '20' (length=2)
      4 => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string '07' (length=2)
          1 => string 'www.admin.testweb.fr' (length=19)
          2 => string '1' (length=1)
```

This array respresent the **amount of visits for my websites** but
you can see that the values **[‘08’][‘1’]** and  **[‘08’][‘2’]** are identicals (only ‘www.’ differs) 
I want to merge  those cells and add their value (because it’s the same site !) in order to get the total amount of visits for a site with it’s two hostnames.

Consider **$sites** as an array of Site Object (websites). 
the **getHost()** method will return the site host for exemple ‘my-host.fr’ without the ‘www’
consider **$statsPerMonth** array explained above

finally consider this algorithm

```
foreach ($statsPerMonth as $actualMonth => $stats) {
            foreach($sites as $site) {
                $siteHost = $site->getHost();
                foreach ($stats as $row) {
                    if (strstr($row['1'], $siteHost)) {
                        if(isset($globalStats[$actualMonth][$siteHost])) {
                            $globalStats[$actualMonth][$siteHost] = $globalStats[$actualMonth][$siteHost] + $row['2'];
                        } else {
                            $globalStats[$actualMonth][$siteHost] = 0;
                            $globalStats[$actualMonth][$siteHost] = $globalStats[$actualMonth][$siteHost] + $row['2'];
                        }
                    }
                    if(!isset($globalStats[$actualMonth][$siteHost])) {
                        $globalStats[$actualMonth][$siteHost] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This algorithm return the **$globalStats** array in this form

```
array (size=3)
  '08' => 
    array (size=43)
      'carrosserie-la-cascade.reseau-fivestar.fr' => int 1
      'audigie-espace-auto.reseau-fivestar.fr' => int 15
      'carrosserie-abberis-fivestar.fr' => int 16
      'carrosserie-arenales-jonathan.reseau-fivestar.fr' => int 0
'07' => 
    array (size=43)
      'carrosserie-la-cascade.reseau-fivestar.fr' => int 2
      'audigie-espace-auto.reseau-fivestar.fr' => int 20
      'carrosserie-abberis-fivestar.fr' => int 0
      'carrosserie-arenales-jonathan.reseau-fivestar.fr' => int 4
'06' => 
    array (size=43)
      'carrosserie-la-cascade.reseau-fivestar.fr' => int 0
      'audigie-espace-auto.reseau-fivestar.fr' => int 29
      'carrosserie-abberis-fivestar.fr' => int 0
      'carrosserie-arenales-jonathan.reseau-fivestar.fr' => int 4
```

This is exaclty what I want but I think we can improve this algorithm to make it more efficient (because the arrays are big). Have you any idea in order to make this algorithm better ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace all "foreach" by "for", such as :

```
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

  }
```

by

```
  $keys = array_keys($array);
  $keyCount = count($keys);

  for($i = 0; $i < $keyCount; $i++) {
    $key = $keys[$i];
    $value = $array[$key];
  }
```

Comment: This will be equal to or slower that the example solution. The dictionary based value lookup is either equally or less efficient than the sequential iteration provided by the original `foreach`. Sometimes more complex isn't faster.